# Адрес первой исполняемой инструкции

Tags: c, unix

Смотрю лекции, и делается следующее:  мы имеем исполняемый файл. Хотим установить адрес первой исполняемой инструкции. Это делаем двумя путями.

Первый путь: запускаем файл и смотрим адрес main
Второй путь: читаем при помощи какой то утилиты исполняемый файл и получаем адрес точки входа

Вопрос: как может вообще храниться адрес в исполняемом файле, если он лежит в файловой системе и не загружен в оперативку? У меня есть предположение что адрес точки входа это может быть смещение относительно начала файла(лектор говорит что это именно адрес, а не смещение). Так ли это?

Comment: Лектор говорит правильно. Это именно адрес, не смещение. но адрес в виртуальной памяти, не в физической.

Comment: "...и не загружен в оперативку"? А при чем здесь "оперативка"? В системах с виртуальной памятью адреса "оперативки" никакой роли не играют вообще.

Answer (score 2):

#### просто в виде дополнения к ответу @DenysSave

точку входа в исполняемом файле [формата elf](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) можно получить многими путями. например:

```
$ readelf -h /bin/true | grep -i entry
  Entry point address:               0x1670
```

или:

```
$ objdump -f /bin/true | grep -i start
start address 0x0000000000001670
```

или прямо в *gdb*:

```
$ gdb /bin/true
...
(gdb) info files
    `/bin/true', file type elf64-x86-64.
    Entry point: 0x1670
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, адрес первой исполняемой инструкции в программе обычно никак не связан с функцией `main`. Поэтому не ясно, как вы собирались решать вашу задачу через "адрес `main`". Если и идти по этому пути, то вам нужно искать адрес `_start`, а не адрес `main`.

Во-вторых, не совсем ясно, что вызвало ваш вопрос о хранении адреса точки входа в исполняемом файле. Расположение исполняемого кода вашей программы в виртуальной памяти процесса известно заранее, еще на стадии линковки программы, по каковой причине нет ничего необычного в том, что адрес точки входа явным образом записан в файл. Т.е. это никакое не смещение, а прямой адрес.

Answer (score 1):

Адрес `main` - совсем не первая исполняемая инструкция. Перед этим выполняется масса разных действий...

А адрес указывается в заголовке файла (если не считать DOS'овских .com-файлов, которые загружались в память с 256-го байта сегмента памяти и выполнялись с первой команды).

У каждого варианта выполнимого файла - свой формат, так что с каждым надо разбираться отдельно, где именно лежит этот адрес в файле. Но операционная система знает, где его прочесть и как передать ему управление после загрузки в память и подготовительных действий.

Вот, например, [как это делалось в DOS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.EXE). В Unix, понятно, структура иная, но принцип остается тем же - выполнимый файл содержит не только код, но и информацию о том, как им воспользоваться.

**Update** Рекомендую книжицу "[Операционные системы](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0310-6.html)", там об этом неплохо рассказывается. Что старая - не так важно, я смотрел издание 2017 года - особой разницы нет, по крайней мере в таких глобальных вещах, как процессы, память и т.п.

Comment: Думаю, стоит добавить, что для каждого процесса система маппит адреса. И потому это вовсе не странно для программы - знать заранее, где будут её инструкции.

Answer (score 1):

В UNIX-подобных системах используется [ELF-формат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) исполняемого файла, в заголовке которого среди прочей информации (тип файла, тип системы и т.п) указан также виртуальный адрес точки входа, которому система передает управление при запуске процесса.